# How do i implement std::all_of function correctly to verify part of a string?

Tags: c++, string, std

I am trying to verify parts of a string (License plates in my case with a total of 7 characters that look like `"000 ABC"`) so that it respects a certain format. Here I am using `std::all_of()` to check if the argument passed in my function starts with 3 numbers and ends with 3 letters with a space in between. The code snippet I have as an example is this :

```
#include <algorithm> // <---- line 8
. . .
. . .

bool validateLicensePlate (const std::string& p_license_plate)
{
    int plate_length = p_license_plate.length();

    if (plate_length == 7 && p_license_plate[3] == ' ')
    {
        if (std::all_of(p_license_plate[0], p_license_plate[2], isdigit))   // <---- line 20
        {
            if (std::all_of(p_license_plate[4], p_license_plate[6], isalpha))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
. . .
. . .
}
```

But when I try compiling the program, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from ../src/validationFormat.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_InputIterator std::__find_if_not(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Predicate) [with _InputIterator = char; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:566:32:   required from ‘_IIter std::find_if_not(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = char; _Predicate = int (*)(int) throw ()]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:509:40:   required from ‘bool std::all_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = char; _Predicate = int (*)(int) throw ()]’
../src/validationFormat.cpp:20:76:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:173:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘__iterator_category(char&)’
        std::__iterator_category(__first));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show all compilation errors ***as plain text***, instead of a completely unreadable images. All questions on stackoverflow.com must include all pertinent information in the question itself, as plain text.

Comment: `std::all_of` takes iterators as parameters.  If you wanted to verify if the entire string was all digits, how would you do that?  If you cannot figure that out, take a look at the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) and observe the sample usage.

Comment: Ok sorry ! i replaced the image with plain text.

Comment: `p_license_plate[0]` is a string element, not an input iterator. The address of an element `&p_license_plate[0]` is an input iterator.

Comment: The thing is i only want to verify parts of the string for digits, and an other part for letters. Maybe it isn't possible with std::all_of. I just thought it would look cleaner like that rather than using two for loops for example.

Comment: Okay i see ! thanks S.M.

Comment: @CharlesLamarche It is possible with `std::all_of` -- you are not passing iterators to that function -- that's the issue.  Again, look at the sample usage at the page I linked to.  If anything after looking at that link, your question should be "how do I provide an iterator to position x in a string", and not that `std::all_of` "doesn't work".

Comment: The second parameter of `std::all_if` must be behind the last element. I suppose you wish `p_license_plate[3]` instead of `p_license_plate[2]`. All elements *before* `p_license_plate[3]` must be checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide iterators to `std::all_of`, not the values that are at the location.

In this case, the iterator is simply a pointer to one of the string elements, for example `&s[0]` is an iterator to the first element in `s`, while `s[0]` is the element.  You are to provide the former, not the latter.

Having said this, here is an example, using not the address-of syntax, but the `std::string::iterator` and using `begin()`/`end()` and using an offset to denote the iterators to use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

bool isValidLicense(const std::string& s)
{
   // lambdas for checking a digit character
   auto isdig = [] (char ch) { return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); };

   // lambda for checking if an alpha character
   auto islet = [] (char ch) { return std::isalpha(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)); };

   // return if the string matches all the criteria shown
   return s.length() == 7 &&   // must be 7 characters
          s[3] == ' ' &&      // fourth character is a space
          std::all_of(s.begin(), s.begin() + 3, isdig) &&  // first 3 are all digits
          std::all_of(s.begin() + 4, s.end(), islet);  // last 3 digits are letters
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << isValidLicense("abc 123") << "\n" << isValidLicense("123 abc");
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

The same thing would have been achieved if you did the "address-of" version:

```
   return s.length() == 7 &&   // must be 7 characters
          s[3] == ' ' &&      // fourth character is a space
          std::all_of(&s[0], &s[3], isdig) &&  // first 3 are all digits
          std::all_of(&s[4], &s[7], islet);  // last 3 digits are letters
```